# UPDATE query returns "Error: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: mysql, c

I've got this annoying error when I try to run an UPDATE query in c-code.
Can't figure out why I get it and I have searched and mainly found solutions for SELECT and in web-code

Here is my simplified code loop

```
MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES;
CHAR sql[2048], sqltmp[200], stmp[200];
INT Cellindex = -1;
CELL celltab[MAXCELLS];  // array of struct Cell's with data 
memcpy((CHAR *) celltab, argv, noOfCells * sizeof (CELL)); // from in-parameter argv

for (Cellindex = 0; Cellindex < MAXSAMPLES; Cellindex++){
  sprintf(sql, "UPDATE celltab SET name=\'%s\'", (len(name) ? (name): "\0\n"));  
  sprintf(sqltmp, ", sect = %d", (celltab[Cellindex].sect ? (celltab[Cellindex].sect): 0));
  strcat (sql, sqltmp);  
  sprintf(sqltmp, ", ptyp = %d", (celltab[Cellindex].ptyp ? (celltab[Cellindex].ptyp): 0));  
  strcat (sql, sqltmp);  
  sprintf(sqltmp, "WHERE celltab_id = %d", (Cellindex + 1)); // no ; in c-code run query
  strcat(sql, sqltmp);
  
if (conn != NULL) { // initiated earlier in code
      RowsAffected = mysql_query(conn, sql); // run the query
      WT("%s",mysql_error(conn));            // print any errors
      mysql_fetch_row(res);                  // fetch any result
      mysql_free_result(res);                // drop it and go for next Q
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you have outstanding results. Maybe some statement before returned more rows than you processed. Before you can proceed you must process all the results. `UPDATE` should always return a single row, so the problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

What I do in my code is this:

```
while(mysql_more_results(m_connection))
    mysql_next_result(m_connection);

MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(m_connection);
mysql_free_result(result);
```

But of course, you may need to look at your code if this is desired for your particular  usecase, or if you have to do something with the results.

Comment: Thanks Devolus, have tried further and stiill can't get it to work however though identified a problem in my SQL question when I shall add optional char to update ie not always a char exist othervise null. '''sprintf(sqltmp, ", mpx = \'%c\'", (emptyflag ? (celltab[Cellindex].mpx): ' ')); ''' doesn't give properly mpx = 'a' or mpx = ''